# Getting error "Failed to parse TextMessage payload=[CONNECT" in STOMP while connecting t

Tags: spring, stomp, sockjs

Hi all I trying to connect to STOMP end point in Spring boot app and getting this error when ever I connect to it using STOMP.js and sock.js

```
o.s.w.s.m.StompSubProtocolHandler        : Failed to parse TextMessage payload=[CONNECT
ac..], byteCount=523, last=true] in session b9ql5g3w. Sending STOMP ERROR to client.

org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompConversionException: Illegal header: '                setConnected(true);'. A header must be of the form <name>:[<value>].
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.readHeaders(StompDecoder.java:224) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.decodeMessage(StompDecoder.java:138) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder.decode(StompDecoder.java:111) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.BufferingStompDecoder.decode(BufferingStompDecoder.java:133) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageFromClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:234) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:307) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:56) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:58) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.delegateMessages(AbstractSockJsSession.java:385) [spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at ..............................................................
```

and my javascipt code is

```
 function connect() {
            var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/Presence', function(greeting){
                    console.log(greeting.body);

                     showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).userId,JSON.parse(greeting.body).status,JSON.parse(greeting.body).imageUrl);

                });
            });
        }
```

I am also using spring boot security. and my Websocket Config and endpont are

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
        @SendTo("/topic/Presence")
        public UserPresences greeting(String message) throws Exception {

            Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
            return new UserPresences();
        }

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, Zahid maybe you also had it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092662/failed-to-parse-textmessage-payload-unsubscrib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by changing code on the client side

```
function connect() {
            var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect('','', function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/Presence', function(greeting){
                    console.log(greeting.body);

                     showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).userId,JSON.parse(greeting.body).status,JSON.parse(greeting.body).imageUrl);

                });
            });
        }
```